# Is possible to save logs in cluster instead in nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to know it is possible to save logs file in the cluster of Google cloud with kubernetes, I used Persistent Volume to try this, but the files only save in the node of the pod deployed.To reference I follow this doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/.

Comment: The typical way is running a log aggregator like fluentd to send to an index like Loki or Elasticsearch, but you can also have fluentd write to a local persistent volume instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

A centralized logging solution called [cluster-level logging](https://www.loggly.com/use-cases/kubernetes-cluster-level-logging/#:%7E:text=cluster%2Dlevel%20logging.-,Cluster%2DLevel%20Logging,-What%20is%20cluster) allows you to collect, store and analyze logs from all the pods and containers within the cluster.

To implement this in kubernetes, you need a log aggregator that can collect logs from various sources within the cluster like fluentd, fluent bit and logstash. These log aggregators collect logs from each node or container and forward them to a centralized location.

You might also need a storage solution where you can store the aggregated logs. Your options include cloud-native services like [Google Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging) and Amazon CloudWatch Logs.